How to Bid a Double Void
Background: This was not a setup, but it wasn't random either. Many of our supplies were water damaged, so we had a lot of distractions. Here is what probably happened: If a new deck is put through a shuffling machine only twice, you will get something like this [see new conclusion in follow-up at bottom]. If I am using the shuffling machine, I usually put the cards through at least 7 times. You can comment on the weirdness of the hands, but that is not my question.
Question: Can South open 2C (strong)? Is there a better opening bid? How can N-S get to 7D?
Some tables were at 6H in the West. Some at 7D in the South. I was North, partner opened 3D or 4D (can't remember) and we eventually let E-W play 6H.
7D will make on a likely Ace of Clubs lead. If not, you can use a ruffing finesse on the Club Ace.

Shuffling follow-up:
I ran some tests with a new ACBL deck. The remaining pictures show the entire deck before dealing. Note that the aces are adjacent to the deuces of each suit, not the kings.

After one perfect riffle shuffle. Note that I didn't actually use the machine for this test, I interleaved the cards by hand. This creates 7-6-0-0 distribution with odd and even ranks. 2-4-6-8... 3-5-7-9...

After two perfect riffle shuffles. This creates 13-0-0-0 distribution in each hand.

After three perfect riffle shuffles. This creates 7-6-0-0 distribution with consecutive ranks.

After four perfect riffle shuffles. A given hand will have all 4 suits of a rank. One hand will have all the face cards.

Three riffle shuffles give the result closest to the deal in this question. The shuffling machine won't interleave perfectly, so there will be slight variations. Most likely cause: I was distracted and only did 3 machine riffle shuffles instead of my usual 7 or more.
Conclusion: Be careful when using machine shufflers on new decks.
I read somewhere that cards should be shuffled a minimum of 7 times. I normally do this with a few cuts interspersed.
I am the only one who uses the machine shuffler. I get there early and start shuffling. As other people arrive, they shuffle by hand.

Given the near perfection of the machine shufflers, it's unlikely that 7 riffle shuffles is enough. I'd go for 9 or even 10. In practice, I always did a quick scramble followed by 7 or 8 hand-riffle shuffles to get a chance at good randomness.

As South you care only about 2 cards: the minor suit aces. Those are roughly:

11% to both be in Partner's hand (as ⅓ * ⅓) ;
44% to be split between partner and opponents (as 2 *  ⅔ * ⅓); and
44% to both be absent from partner's hand (as ⅔ * ⅔) .

However opponents can almost certainly outbid you in at least one of the majors - perhaps even in notrump. Your goal should be on how to best shut them out of the auction; so you should make the best pre-empt available, which is to open 6 diamonds. This is 55% to make; forces the opponents to guess at the 6 or 7 level with the least possible information; and might encourage partner to take the sacrifice (?) in 7 diamonds holding the diamond ace and something else.
Opening two clubs - or, in fact, anything else below 6 diamonds - I believe simply earns any bad result you get, by giving opponents additional information before their guess at the slam level.
Finally, there's a vital caveat for whenever you are considering an opening of 2 clubs: that call should ONLY be made with hands that either:

requires only one additional call to complete a description for partner, who then takes over the auction; or
requires only one call from Partner before taking over the auction in hand.

This hand resembles neither of these cases - and should never be opened 2 clubs on that basis alone.

It's true that just based on your own hand, you have a 55% chance to make 6D. But just based on your own hand it is very unlikely that opponents are anywhere close to a slam. Your hand already contains 12 points. I think your analysis works only with the meta argument: my hand looks like the shuffling was broken, hence opponents hands will look like that as well.

@quarague - but it's quite possible for opponents to have a good sacrifice, and you want to make it hard for them to find it.  In a good field, if your slam makes, +800 could very well be a bottom board.

@quarague a common piece of advice is "if you have a regular hand, other players likely have a regular hand; if you have a shaped hand, other players likely have a shaped hand". Here you are missing 26 major cards; on average each opponent holds more than 8 of them. At my level (which is hardly stellar), an opponent with 6+/x or 5/4+ in majors will make some noise over a 2C-2D auction. Whether their partner will then find a sacrifice at the 6 or 7 level, I am not sure, but why give them a chance?

I'm not sure whether I open 1D or 5D or 6D or 4N (which ace (not how many) do you have?) as South.  (Opening 3D or 4D can't be right; you can see you will almost always make at least 5D no matter what anyone else has.)
If South opens 1D, West should bid 4N - showing an extremely distributional hand with hearts and clubs (the 2 lowest unbid suits) - this is an extension of unusual 2N at a higher level.
I would expect West would bid 5H over either 4N or 5D.  It's not clear whether or not to bid 6H over 6D.
Everyone is guessing at this point.
Note, looking at all the hands, N/S shouldn't be allowed to play 7D; E/W have a good sacrifice at 7H.
2C with this South hand is extremely unwise - as you can see from this hand, West next bids 4H or 5H or 4N (any 2 suiter, or maybe specifically one of H/C or S/D, depending on agreements), and N/S get to start at the 5 level with neither of them knowing what suit their partner has.

Other answers have told you why you shouldn't open this 2♣ (they can and will outbid you, and you won't get to show your suit easily).
But you asked "Can South", not "Should South".  That is a legal question, and depends on where you play.
The Laws themselves don't restrict any meaning for any call; but in Duplicate Bridge, they allow the Regulating Authority to regulate meanings of calls.  Many, including the one for North America (ACBL), do restrict 2♣ openings with "tricks but not points" (more particularly, "tricks, but not defensive points"), because of hands like these where you make your strongest call and they likely have game (or even slam!)
In the ACBL, in a limited game, you may not open 2♣ on hands like these; in the open games, you may, but must Alert your opponents to your tendencies.  Other RAs do different things.
But you were talking about a mechanical shuffler, so very likely you are not playing duplicate, sanctioned or otherwise.    The Rubber Bridge Law 40 effectively says "you play 'normal bridge', unless your agreements have been explained beforehand or you and your opponents agree to explain them when bid.  Oh, by agreement, restrictions can be made on partnership understandings" (and the house rules, or the club rules, almost always do).
So, whether you can is up to the game you play in.  Whether you should is up to your partner, and how conservative your opponents are.  Oh, and how comfortable you are with, if you do "convince" them to stay out of your 2♣ auction, the explosion when they realize they can make 4♥ (on a slightly different hand).  That explosion is unpleasant, as someone who has been the director when it happened at my club can attest.

Our club played ACBL games for many years, but we haven't recently, we don't have an official Director anymore. We play a casual duplicate game. Some people also play at ACBL clubs, so we try to follow ACBL rules for consistency. Are you saying that mechanical shuffling machines are not allowed in ACBL games? Can you point to the rule number so I can educate myself.

No, any shuffling method approved by the Director that produces random hands is acceptable (Law 6E4).  Just almost always if the hands are dealt with mechanical assistance, it is with a dealing machine these days (that deals a randomly generated board).  It was just a guess that a shuffler for only one deck at a time was used in a non-duplicate game.

Having said that, if the shuffler is used only twice on regular boards, well, you can see the evidence of the previous board in this hand from a sorted deck.  The same lack of randomness will show up on all the rest of the boards, if players are looking for it (recognizable on a passout, say, or when North had ♠AKQJT8764 on board 4 last week).  This hand itself is evidence of "not 'wholly random expectations'" required for boards.  In fact "inadequate shuffling", mechanical or hand-done, is well known for creating flatter hands than expected.
